# Target paragraphs containing only images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div (blog post) containing multiple paragraphs.

Some of these contain text, other text + images and other only images.

I would like to target only the paragraphs containing only images and set `text-align:center`

Is this possible using only css or is js required?

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: jquery sounds ok considering no css posibility

Comment: @VladimirStarkov thanks for the  example. You are targeting divs that contain only images. I would like to target paragraphs containing only images and no text.

Appreciate it

Comment: without text my solution works too. see [fork demo](http://jsfiddle.net/matmuchrapna/mXRSn/8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following adds a special CSS class to all p tags that only contain img tags and whitespace:

```
$('.blog-post p').each(function(i){          // For each paragraph
    if ( ($(this).find('img').length) &&     // If there's an image
         (!$.trim($(this).text()).length))   // and there's no text
    {
        $(this).addClass('imgOnly');         // Add a special CSS class
    }
});
```

The `trim()` function is used with `text()` to determine if the text only contains whitespace.

Sample content:

```
<div class="blog-post">
    <p>Text</p>
    <p><span>Text</span></p>
    <p><img/></p>                   <!-- CSS class will be added -->
    <p>Text <img/></p>
    <p><span>Text</span><img/></p>
    <p><img/> Text <img/></p>
    <p><img/><img/></p>             <!-- CSS class will be added -->
    <p><img/> <img/></p>            <!-- CSS class will be added -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This example will help you: **[demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matmuchrapna/mXRSn/7/)**

**jQuery code:**

```
$(function() {
    var divs = $('.blog-post > div');

    $.each(divs, function(i, div) {
        /* cache variable */
        var $div = $(div);
        if ( !($div.find('p')[0]) ) { /* if there are no one p tag inside div */
            $div.addClass('only-images');
        }
    });

});
```

**CSS:**

```
.blog-post > .only-images {
    background-color: red; /* color is demo only */
}
```

So my example will add class only to third div containing only images in this example **HTML** markup:

```
<div class="blog-post">
    <div>
        <p>some text</p>
        <p>some text</p>
        <p>some text</p>
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>some text</p>
        <img src="//placekitten.com/g/100/100" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div> <!-- only this div would be applied class `only-images` customizable by css  -->
        <img src="//placekitten.com/g/100/100" alt="" />
        <img src="//placekitten.com/g/100/100" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use javascript and write a function for it, you'll be best of using the javascript library Jquery. When you have a function for it you can later add new paragraphs and images without the need to write more code.

I would have written an example but I don't have much time. I hope I helped you a little

Answer (score 0):

Css is not enough. You may use Css rules based on parents, but not based on children. For example you may target all images that appear inside paragraphs. The properties will apply to the images, and not to the paragraph. Example:

```
p img
{
   /* properties */
}
```

Options remain Javascript or server-side, for example you could assign a specific class name to the paragraph based on the content (.imageOnly or .mixedContent).

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this without jQuery and I came up with the following:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(function(p) {

    // if there's no image, stop
    if (p.querySelector('img') === null) {
        return;
    }

    // if there's text, stop
    if (p.innerText.trim() !== "") {
        return;
    }

    // otherwise, mark the paragraph
    p.classList.add('img-only');
});
```

Only tested on modern browsers.